# urdf parsing error

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In tutorial :

http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Parse%20a%20urdf%20file

When I run:

```
~/catkin_ws$ ./devel/lib/testbot_description/parser /src/testbot_description/urdf/my_robot.urdf
```

I get:

```
[ERROR] [1391452425.205963339]: Could not open file [/src/testbot_description/urdf/my_robot.urdf] for parsing.
[ERROR] [1391452425.206094879]: Failed to parse urdf file
```

I checked in the directories, both files are already present but still error! Kindly help!

My Ros: Hydro
My OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/125746/urdf-parsing-error/) by [mudassar](https://answers.ros.org/users/10726/mudassar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 22 on 2014-02-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2014-02-03**:
what do you see when you run  "ls /src/testbot_description/urdf/my_robot.urdf"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a dot missing in the second tutorial.

From your catkin workspace, run: ./devel/lib/testbot_description/parser ./src/testbot_description/urdf/my_robot.urdf

It worked for me.

---

Originally posted by [mudassar](https://answers.ros.org/users/10726/mudassar/) with karma: 22 on 2014-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1